# run js on page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a google chrome extension, and I need JavaScript to run on every page loaded.

I have tried looking everywhere for an answer, but I cannot find one anywhere. Everything is outdated.

This is my current code:

```
function reddenPage() {
  alert("yay!")
}



chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: reddenPage
  });
  }
);
```

Comment: Simply declare a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), you don't need the background script for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated) and then check the [`TabStatus`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-TabStatus).

```js
function reddenPage() {
  alert("yay!")
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo) => {
  // checking status
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId },
      func: reddenPage // should be "func" instead of "function"
    });
  }
});
```

Note that you don't need `{ tabId: tabId }` because `{ tabId }` is the same. It is called "Shorthand property names".

Comment: @ijustwantawnsers The `tabs` permssion